# Comparing Strings Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data and I created a form to enter new data to be added to the list. Upon the click of a button it will take the information (name and email address) from the form and add it to the corresponding sheets in alphabetical order. There are linked cells involved so I can't just add this to the bottom and sort. Instead, I have it searching the last name cell in the correct sheets to insert a row into the correct location.

This was working as expected for the most part until I came along a possibly unique situation that I can't figure out.

Basically, I have an if statement checking to see if the name is a duplicate and afterwards checking to see if the if the new name should be inserted.

```
    For i = 2 To lastrow

        ''^^IF STATEMENT CHECKING FOR DUPLICATE^^''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''vvIF STATEMENT CHECKING TO ADD DATAvv'''

        ElseIf StrComp(lastname, searchl) = 1 And StrComp(lastname, searchl2) = -1 Then

            Sheets("Master List").Range("A" & i).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert (xlDown)
            Sheets("Master List").Range("A" & i + 1).Value = firstname
            Sheets("Master List").Range("B" & i + 1).Value = lastname
            Sheets("Master List").Range("C" & i + 1).Value = fullname
```

Variables searchl and searchl2 are the last names from search rows i and i + 1, respectively.

My problem is that when I tried to add the last name "Kralik" it tried to insert the data between the last names "Day" and "de Castro"

Originally, I tried comparing the names using the line of code below:

```
ElseIf lastname > searchl And lastname < searchl2 Then
```

This executed the exact same way as the code outlined above. I then inserted a break point and decided to use the StrComp method for troubleshooting. Comparing "Kralik" to "Day" produced results expected but the problem occurs when comparing "Kralik" to "de Castro". For some reason, the code thinks "Kralik" is less than "de Castro" and enters the if statement to insert the data at that location. Even more head scratching for me is that I opened a new workbook and quickly typed "Kralik" into A1, "de Castro" into A2 and the formula "=A1>A2" into A3. The formula gave a result TRUE which is what I would have expected from VBA as well.

EDIT: After more tests, I think it must have something to do with the capitalization of "Kralik" vs. "de Castro" my code works as expected as long as the "k" in "Kralik" is uncapitalized. I will use the UCase method on my variables and come back with the results.

EDIT 2: Using UCase works as well. Outlined by GSerg's answer below as to why my original method was not working.

Comment: `StrComp(lastname, searchl, vbTextCompare)` and `StrComp(lastname, searchl2, vbTextCompare)`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Will also come back with my test of using UString on my variables just for anyone reading, but I will be using your method in my code. Thanks again!

Comment: Side note: using `StrComp` with a comparison mode argument is a much more robust way to fix this than upper-casing the strings for comparison purposes; many programmers get bitten by this upper/lower-casing trick when they start dealing with different (non-ANSI) text encodings - best to learn & use the *correct* way first, that way you don't have bad habits to un-learn later ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel formulas use case insensitive comparisons by default.
VBA uses case sensitive comparisons by default.

If you want case insensitive comparisons, either put

```
Option Compare Text
```

at the beginning of the code module to make all text comparisons in that code module case insensitive by default, or request a comparison type in each specific comparison:

```
ElseIf StrComp(lastname, searchl, vbTextCompare) = 1 And StrComp(lastname, searchl2, vbTextCompare) = -1 Then
```

On top of that, you should be using binary search in your particular case to find the position to insert. [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) with `match_type = 1` will return you position in a sorted list where the value should go.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'm fairly new with working in Excel VBA. Could you please elaborate on how the match function can help me?

Comment: @drowsy.dan Given a list of last names in `A1:A100`, `Application.Match(lastname, Sheets("Master List").Range("A1:A100"), 1)` will return the row number where the `lastname` should be inserted. If there is a header, you should pass the address without it (`A2:A100`), and the list must be sorted to begin with.

Comment: Wonderful! That is much more useful than using a For loop and checking a series of If statements. Thanks again!

Comment: One last question about using match. Why is it that for something that should go at the beginning of the list (For example, I was testing a last name of "AAA"), the function returns a mismatch error?

Comment: @drowsy.dan Because it [*"finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value"*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), and if the lookup_value must go in the beginning, there is no "value that is less than or equal to lookup_value", and *"If `MATCH` is unsuccessful in finding a match, it returns the `#N/A` error value"*. Use `IsError` on the result.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!